# How to minimize chromedriver's resource usage?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium (Python) to run multiple chromedriver instances on a Raspberry Pi. Preferably I would like to run as many instances as the Pi's hardware can manage, hence a lower resource usage will be beneficial. Running a headless chromedriver is unfortunately not possible due to chromedriver not allowing DRM content to load in this mode.

A starting point would most likely be to optimize switches. A very comprehensive list of available switches can be found [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). The list contains a lot of switches, and I was wondering if anyone has a list of switches optimizing performance that I can use as a starting point.

In addition I would like to mention that it is not important for me to actually see what happens on the browser window. So, might it be relevant to e.g. prevent images from loading or hide/move the browser window of screen?

Comment: you might consider using HTMLUnit for this... http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @pcalkins the sourceforge page says its for java?

Comment: requests-html works sometimes

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, I am particularly interested in how to minimize usage for chromedriver specifically.

Comment: hadn't realized that HTMLUnit was Java only...

Comment: have you looked into using `PhantomJS` instead of chrome? it's way lighter on resources and can be driven with `selenium` by initializing the driver with `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()`

Comment: PhantomJS is unfortunately not longer actively maintained. Even though it might work now, I’d rather build on something more durable

Comment: chrome://flags/#disable-best-effort-tasks you can enable this flag and check if there is any improvement in performance https://www.ghacks.net/2019/02/11/chrome-shutdown-memory-use/